# INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Routing Type: bad value for restricted picklist field: SkillBased: [RoutingType]

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am inserting Pending service routing but getting error in inserting it

```java
  PendingServiceRouting psrObj = new PendingServiceRouting
                  (
                  CapacityWeight = 1,
                  IsReadyForRouting = FALSE,
                  RoutingModel  = 'MostAvailable',
                 RoutingPriority = 1,
                 RoutingType = 'SkillsBased',
                 ServiceChannelId = getChannelId(),
                 WorkItemId = chat.Id,
                 PushTimeout = 0
    

         );
           
         
     insert psrObj;
```

> Exception - Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Routing Type: bad value for
> restricted picklist field: SkillBased: [RoutingType]

Please tell the steps i have to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please check if Skill based routing is enabled in your org in omni-channel settings

Comment: This issue is solved now but i am getting another error again        Error - Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: WorkItemId duplicates value on record with id: 0JR03000000ChFE: []

Comment: WorkItemId is a unique field which means you can't create more than one record of same workItemId.